# Problem of Ages (Problema das Idades)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, problem-solving

*English:*
Somebody help me with this challenge? It's very confusing:

> Today, both me and my younger brother are between $10$ and $20$ years old. Also, our ages are expressed by prime numbers and the next time this occurs will be in $18$ years. Determine my age knowing that the age of our eldest brother, whose age today is also a prime number, which is one greater than the sum of the ages of me and my younger brother.

*Português:*
Alguém me ajuda com este desafio? É muito confuso:

> Eu e meu irmão caçula temos idades entre $10$ e $20$ anos e hoje nossas idades são expressas ambas por números primos, fato que se repetirá pela próxima vez daqui há $18$ anos. Determine minha idade sabendo que a idade de nosso irmão mais velho, que, hoje, também é um número primo, é uma unidade maior do que a soma das nossas idades.

My thoughts:
Primes between $10$ and $20$ are $\{ 11, 13,17,19\}$. The primes between $29$ and $37$ ($18$ years later) are $\{ 29,31,37 \}$.

Comment: Both given answers assume that the brothers ages are distinct, which is not necessarily implied by the term "younger brother". You need to formally exclude this, which you can, using the fact, that the event "both ages are prime" will occur more recent than in 18 years.

Answer (score 2):

Information:

The prime numbers are between 10 and 20: $\{ 11,13,17,19 \}$.

The ages of the two boys are one of those numbers.

Eighteen years after the minimum age of two one turn will $11+18=29$ and the maximum age is $19+18=37$.

The primes between 29 and 37 are: $\{ 29,31,37 \}$.

Remarks:

$$11+18=29$$

$$13+18=31$$

$$17+18=35$$ Is not prime, so the age of any of the boys can be 17.

$$19+18=29$$

Conclusions:

The ages of the boys can be

11 e 13;

11 e 19; or

13 e 19;

Because one is older than the other.

$$11+13+1=25$$ As 25 is not prime, we discard this first possibility;

$$11+19+1=31$$ As 31 is prime, this is a possibility;

$$13+19+1=33$$ As 33 is not prime, we discard this third possibility;

So we have only one possibility which is 11 and 19

Since the problem asks "Determine my age" (age of the oldest, between the two). The final answer is **19 years**.

Comment: My language is Portuguese, excuse any errors, I'm not very good at English.

Answer (score 1):

11 and 19: 11+18=29, 19+18=37, 11+19+1=31. No other combination satisfies the condition: 17 is out (17+18=35), 13 is out (11+13+1=25, 13+19+1=33).

Comment: It's great to have a final answer, but *just* putting the final answer and nothing else does not really count as helpful. Customarily solutions should have explanation, so consider adding some! Just some friendly advice...

Comment: @Doctor Dan: What guarantees that the answer is unique?